# TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects. how to convert list to string

Tags: python, string, list, typeerror

I have the following python code:

```
if str(fv["f"])=="AG":
        nf=str(fv["f"])+" "+ in +" ("+"\'"+str(fv["v"])+"\'"+")"
```

which gives the output as:

```
nf=AG in ('abc,xyz,ef')
```

but the required output is:

```
nf=AG in ('abc','xyz','ef')
```

I tried placing `split(",")` at `str(fv["v"]).split(",")`
but it gives me TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects. please help how can I get the output.

Comment: Please edit the code in your question so it is a [mre] with all variables initialized, any needed imports etc. Anyone should be able to make a single copy/paste from your question into a file and _without adding anything_ run your code to see the same problem as you.

Comment: Try it yourself: copy your two lines of code into a file and (try to) run them. Now fix the errors until you can run your code and update the code in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
str(tuple(str(fv["v"]).split(',')))
```

will probably give you what you want but if you give more information there is definitely a better way to write this.

What does `fv['v']` consist of?

Comment: Thanks, this works.. fv[v] consists of list of values like abc,xyz,ef etc...

Comment: if so you could have just used ```str(tuple(fv["v"]))``` and it would have worked also 
and for a better readable string you can just use ```nf= f'{fv["f"]} in {tuple(fv["v"])}' ```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on type of `fv["v"]` but probably this will work:

```py
if str(fv["f"]) == "AG":
    nf = "{} in {}".format(fv["f"], tuple(fv["v"]))
```

When you provide the result of `type(fv["v"])` this answer would be corrected.

Comment: fv[v] consists of list of values like abc,xyz,ef etc...

Comment: Then use `tuple` to convert it and print as is.